# I've implemented winwheel app for single browser, now I want to synchronise its spins for all access

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have implemented winwheel application for single machine browser, now i want to synchronize its spins for any machines browser.

I have used..

Winwheel.js
TweenMax.min.js

working fine for single machine but now I want to synchronize it all over.

I am posting some part of code.. winwheel should be spin at a time for all.. should get unique results

My Code's part:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Winwheel.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            setTimeout(function(){ startSpin() }, 20000);
            setTimeout(function(){ timecounting() }, 1000);

            let theWheel = new Winwheel({
                'outerRadius'     : 200,        
                'responsive'      : true,          
                'innerRadius'     : 75,         
                'textFontSize'    : 72,         
                'textOrientation' : 'vertical', 
                'textAlignment'   : 'outer',    
                'numSegments'     : 10,         
                'segments'        :             
                [                               
                   {'fillStyle' : '#ee1c24', 'text' : '1'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#3cb878', 'text' : '2'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#f6989d', 'text' : '3'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#00aef0', 'text' : '4'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#f26522', 'text' : '5'},                   
                   {'fillStyle' : '#e70697', 'text' : '6'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#fff200', 'text' : '7'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#f6989d', 'text' : '8'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#ee1c24', 'text' : '9'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#3cb878', 'text' : '0'},                   

                ],
                'animation' :           
                {
                    'type'     : 'spinToStop',
                    'duration' : 10,    
                    'spins'    : 10,     
                    'callbackFinished' : alertPrize,
                    'callbackSound'    : playSound,   
                    'soundTrigger'     : 'pin'       
                },
                'pins' :        
                {
                    'number'     : 10,
                    'fillStyle'  : 'silver',
                    'outerRadius': 10,
                    'responsive' : true, 
                }
            });

            var timecounter = 20;
            var winning_no = '';

            let audio = new Audio('tick.mp3');

            function timecounting()
            { 
                if(timecounter>1){ 
                    timecounter=timecounter-1;
                    setTimeout(function(){ timecounting() }, 1000);
                    $('#timeCntPara').html(timecounter);
                    $('#timeCntPara').show();
                }else{
                    $('#timeCntPara').hide();
                }   
            }

            function playSound()
            { 
                audio.play();
            }

            let wheelSpinning = false;            

            function startSpin()
            {
                $('#timeCntPara').hide();

                if (wheelSpinning == false) {

                    theWheel.animation.spins = 10;

                    theWheel.startAnimation();

                    wheelSpinning = true;
                }
            }

            var delay=0;
            function alertPrize(indicatedSegment)
            {                 
                if (indicatedSegment.text == 'LOOSE TURN') {
                    $('#spinres').html('Sorry but you loose a turn.');
                    $("#spinres").show().delay(2000).fadeOut();
                } else if (indicatedSegment.text == 'BANKRUPT') {
                    $('#spinres').html('Oh no, you have gone BANKRUPT!');
                    $("#spinres").show().delay(2000).fadeOut();
                } else {
                    $('#spinres').html('You have won '+indicatedSegment.text);
                    $("#spinres").show().delay(2000).fadeOut();
                }
                theWheel.stopAnimation(false);
                theWheel.rotationAngle = 0;
                wheelSpinning = false;

                // save spin records in db - start
                winning_no = indicatedSegment.text;
                s = {winning_no:winning_no};                

                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: 'php/save.php',
                    data: s,
                    success: function(response) {
                        wait(5000);
                        setTimeout(function(){ startSpin() }, 20000);
                        timecounter=20;
                        setTimeout(function(){ timecounting() }, 1000);
                    }
                })
                // save spin records in db - end
            }

            function wait(ms){
               var start = new Date().getTime();
               var end = start;
               while(end < start + ms) {
                 end = new Date().getTime();
              }
            }
    </script>
```

please give me idea..

Comment: i have implemented winwheel.js relevant scripts for winwheel app.. working fine.. just want to make its spins synchronize all over.. any idea??

Comment: Where is the [mcve] in your question?

Comment: now please check the edits ....

Comment: please suggest me any idea??

Answer (score 0):

I would look to use Push Notifications for this. Push out a "spin" command to all the browsers listening for the event.

I have used https://pusher.com/channels before and think this or something similar could do what you would like. In the pusher JS example instead of doing an alert you could trigger the spin of the wheel...

```js
var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
channel.bind('my-event', function(data) {
  if (data.message == 'spin') {
    theWheel.startAnimation();
  }
});
```